# Deleting folder containing file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to send the file `file.txt` from my Rails controller using `send_file`, and then delete the folder containing it.

```
send_file("#{Rails.root}/public/folder/file.txt")
system("rm -rf #{Rails.root}/public/folder")
```

When I tried this, `file.txt` was correctly sent, `file.txt` was correctly deleted, but somehow `folder` was not deleted.

How can I make it delete `folder`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to delete the folder directly with the native ruby method instead of a system command:

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.remove_dir "#{Rails.root}/public/folder", true
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-remove_dir

Comment: On the `require 'FileUtils'` line, it gives error `cannot load such file -- FileUtils`

Comment: With Rails, try to not require the file.

Comment: Or write it lowercase _require 'fileutils'_

Comment: I created a new rails app, a folder in the public directory and used this code in a controller and it works. What are the rights on this folder? Is it a linux/mac or windows system?

Comment: @jeremiemv The server is a linux system. What's interesting is that if I remove the `send_file` line, the deletion works perfectly fine.

Comment: My guess is that send_file opens the file to stream it to the client. Trying to delete it right away, before it finishes to streaming, is then failing!